# Difference between vapour and gas

Tags: terminology

This is the question i have been asking from months to my friends,teachers,and everyone but i haven't got a satisfactory answer yet(in fact i haven't got any answer).These two terms (vapour and gas) are confusing me from a long time and i can't get the difference.I shall be very thankful if someone of you give me a detailed explaination for the question.I m sorry if this question or a similar question have already been asked on the site and i shall be thankful if you provide me the link of the question so that i can get my answer there.

Finally the question is "What is the difference between vapour and gas".

Comment: [In physics a vapor (American) or vapour (British) is a substance in the gas phase at a temperature lower than its critical temperature, which means that the vapor can be condensed to a liquid by increasing the pressure on it without reducing the temperature.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor)

Comment: is it different in chemistry??

Comment: It is a physical phenomenon, not a chemical phenomenon.

Comment: Really??But it comes under the chapter states of matter in my chemistry textbook.

Comment: Changes in the state of matter does not change the chemical composition of the substance (generally).

Comment: Look, i think your and my views are not coinciding,i think change of state have no significance here as i m just asking difference between gas and vapour.

Comment: Forget it, there is no difference.

Comment: DHMO gave you a comprehensive answer. If you are not interested in the change of state, then there is no difference.

Comment: What if i develop my interest in change of state??

Comment: from the second comment;   ... and a gas cannot be liquified by pressure alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think vapor have a temperature near to the condensation point so it can become liquid easily but gas have much higher temperature than it's condensation point hence we need a process to make it liquid for example if steam is at around 100°c then it can be termed as water vapor and if you consider nitrogen it liquifies at -198°c or near to that hence it is referred as gas.